# ActiveMq 'Queue Priority Consumer' Mechanism Not Working Expectedly

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, producer-consumer, consumer

We are using ActiveMq in our application. We need to implement priority consumer mechanism on the queue. We have multiple consumers and we want to treat them as master/slave. So, the master consumer would have higher priority and will consume all messages and once master gets down then the consumer (with higher priority) will consume all requests from the queue.

To Implement this scenario, we came across the mechanism of priority queues. So, we initialized the queues by this way:

```
javax.jms.Queue queue = queueSession.createQueue("myQueue" + "?consumer.priority=" + 127);
```

and remaining slaves nodes were assigned lesser priorities.

But this mechanism is not working expectedly, sometimes it works fine that we get all requests on the consumer with the highest priority but sometimes consumer with lesser priority also start consuming messages while the consumer with the highest priority is working fine.

We have tried it with `consumer.exclusive=true` option as well, with no luck.

**Note:** We are running all components (ActiveMQ, producer and consumer application) locally on the same machine for now, so no network delays involved. And we are running consumers with default prefetch policy.

Is there any other approach to implement this scenario using activeMq or are we  missing any configuration.